# Sanity documents not showing

Tags: javascript, react-native, sanity

Whenever i create a new document in sanity using 'createOrReplace'. It successfully creates the document, but however it doesn't show the newly created document in the home screen.

Note: All the other documents i upload from Sanity Studio displays correctly. Only the ones created with 'createOrReplace' isn't showing

Here is my code if you want to check it:

**Home.jsx**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import { client } from '../lib/client';

import CustomHeader from '../components/CustomHeader.component';
import Post from '../components/Post.component';

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const query = `*[_type == 'post']`
      const post = await client.fetch(query);

      setPosts(post);
    }

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap"
        }}>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <View
              style={{
                display:"flex",
                flexDirection: "row"
              }}
            >
              <Post
                title={post.title}
                desc={post.description}
                image={post.image}
                id={post._id}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

**Create.jsx**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Platform, TextInput, Dimensions, Alert, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import GradiantImage from '../assets/Main/Gradiants/gradient_img.png';

import { storage } from '../firebase/firebase-config';
import { SANITY_TOKEN } from '@env';

const CreatePosts = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState('');

  const pickImage = async () => {
    /*
     * Picks image from the user using expo-image-picker
     * uploads it to firebase storage
     * And sets the imageURL state to the uploaded
     * image's URL in firebase.
     */
  };

  const createPost = async () => {
    if (!title || !desc) return Alert.alert("Error", "Please enter the title and the description");

    const mutations = [
      {
        createOrReplace: {
          _id: 'p.',
          _type: 'post',
          title,
          description: desc,
          image: imageURL
        }
      }
    ]
              
    await fetch(`https://projectIdHidden.api.sanity.io/v2021-06-07/data/mutate/production`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${SANITY_TOKEN}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ mutations })
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Image style={styles.background} source={GradiantImage} />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.androidSafeAreaView}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>
            New Post {title || `"${title}"`}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Your Title'
            style={styles.title}
            value={title}
            onChangeText={text => setTitle(text)}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Your Description'
            style={styles.desc}
            value={desc}
            onChangeText={text => setDesc(text)}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imgContainer} onPress={pickImage}>
            <Image
              style={styles.img}
              source={!image ? require("../assets/Main/select.png") : { uri: image.uri } } />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={!image ? styles.postDisabled : styles.post}
            disabled={!image}
            onPress={createPost}
          >
            <Text style={styles.postTxt}>
              Post!
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cancel} disabled={!image} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
            <Text style={styles.cancelTxt}>
              Cancel
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // ...
})

export default CreatePosts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your documents on a [non-root path](https://www.sanity.io/docs/ids) (`_id: ‘p.’`), which will require a token in order to view them.

Comment: I just went throught the documentation. There they say that it will automatically generate a new I'd but when I try to not include the I'd, it gives me an error